# MTG: Ixidron vs Morph

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-face-down-cards

I couldn't find the answer to this but what happens if you have a face down morph on the field and someone plays Ixidron? Does my morph creature stay face down or do they get turned up?

Answer (score 7):

The text printed on the [Ixidron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIxidron%5d) reads as follows:

> As Ixidron enters the battlefield, turn all other nontoken creatures
>   face down. (They're 2/2 creatures.) Ixidron's power and toughness are
>   each equal to the number of face-down creatures on the battlefield.

As morphed creatures are already face-down they are unaffected.
This is reflected in the Ruling made in 2006:

> **2006-09-25** : Turning a face-down creature face-down typically has no effect; the creature’s status is unchanged.

Comment: Basically, it's like asking you to tap all creatures, and you control a tapped creature. Nothing happens to it. Also, it is considered good form to quote official sources that directly address the issue at hand. Like the Gatherer page you linked: "Turning a face-down creature face-down typically has no effect; the creature’s status is unchanged."